# Scipy sinusoidal fit has a wrong offset

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

Let's say I have the following data

```
data = np.array([0.405, 0.120, 0.093, 0.193, 0.513, 0.780, 0.980, 0.911, 0.681])
```

obtained from an experiment at the following times

```
time = np.array([0, 0.35, 0.7, 1.05, 1.4, 1.75, 2.1, 2.45, 2.8])
```

I want to fit them in Python 3.7 with a **squared sine** function, employing the *curve_fit* function from scipy.optimize:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

function = lambda t, f: np.sin(f * t) ** 2
```

I'm interested only on the frequency of the function, this is why I have just one parameter (together with t). The amplitude is expected to be from 0 to 1. I performed the fit as follows

```
p, c = curve_fit(function, time, data)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(time, data)
plt.plot(time, function(time, p))
```

obtaining tis plot:
[Fit_and_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DGXb.png)

However, as you can see from the picture, the fit begins at point (0,0) thus not resembling the data. The fitted frequency is indeed quite different from the expected one.

I would like to find a way to let the fit start around the first data point, and not always at the origin. Is that possible?

I also know that *curve_fit* accepts also a guess for the fitted parameters, but I don't see how this can change my results. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following graphical Python fitter using your data and a sinc equation, I get a period of 3.072.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([0.0, 0.35, 0.7, 1.05, 1.4, 1.75, 2.1, 2.45, 2.8])
yData = numpy.array([0.405, 0.120, 0.093, 0.193, 0.513, 0.780, 0.980, 0.911, 0.681])


def func(t, center, width):
    return numpy.sin(numpy.pi * (t - center) / width) ** 2.0


initialParameters = numpy.array([max(xData)/2.0, max(xData)])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `sin(f*t)` when `t=0` will be equal to `0` no matter what. I expect you want

```
function = lambda t, f: np.sin(t + f) ** 2
```

which will give
[image: sine curve]

?

Comment: Ok in this way it solves the graphical problem. But if now I want to know, say, the period of my experimental oscillation? Will it simply be p[0]?

Comment: To get the period you'll need to write the function to include the period like `function = lambda t, f, c: np.sin(f * t + c) ** 2`. You can then work it out from `p[0]`. Doing this I need to set `p0` in curve fit to `[0.5, 0.5]` (optimisation is tricky)